# Как установить толщину подчеркивания ссылки через CSS?

Tags: wordpress, css3

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать толщину подчеркивания ссылки и поместить линию под текст ссылки?[image: ссылка]

Answer (score 1):

Для этого есть свойство `box-shadow`

```css
.cool_link {
  color: red;
  font-size: 30px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), 0 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a class="cool_link" href="#">Ссылка</a>
```

Comment: добавь для ссылки `href` и посмотри результат

Comment: @Grundy а что, так сложно добавить `text-decoration: none;`? ОК, поправил ответ. Но вопрос совсем не об этом был.

Comment: конечно сложно! у тебя же в ответе про это ничего не было. Вопрос был про подчеркивание, но ты же не изменил подчеркивание, не добавляя href, ты его просто убрал, и фактически заменив элемент на другой ничего не поменялось бы. Но в вопросе речь шла конкретно о ссылке.

Answer (score 0):

Например, [так](http://codepen.io/VostokSisters/pen/RKJMZK).
А бокс-шадоу затратный)
И может тормозить страницу на мобилках. Его юзать нужно с большим умом, не растрачивать на подчеркивание для ссылок каких-то.

```css
p {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 14pt;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
p::before {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  border-bottom: 10px solid red;
  width: 100%;
}
p:hover:before {
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<p>Ссылка</p>
```

Comment: Есть достоверные источники где почитать про  "бокс-шадоу затратный) И может тормозить страницу на мобилках"?

Comment: @SeVlad, я уже не нашел пример, который сам смотрел. Но там были блоки, штук 400 на странице, у которых был бокс-шадоу, и именно они тормозили страницу при простом скроллинге. И там ещё приводились простые пути решения проблемы, типа не использовать бокс шадоу у элемента при транзишне и всякое такое.  Вообщем-то, я просто думаю, что легче отрисовать псевдоэлемент, чем целый фильтр размытия от элемента.

Comment: @VostokSisters наверное потому, что он затратный, его использует WP в стандартной теме twentyseventeen. Однако у меня есть смутные подозрения, что разработчики этой темы получше нас разбираются в том, что затратно, а что нет.

Comment: @VostokSisters, я не то что бы не верю, но как-то трудно предположить, что css может вызывать тормоза. Не, гипотетически допускаю - рендеринг и всё такое, но вряд ли производители браузеров, поддерживая стандарты такое допустили. Но в принципе разные случаи бывают. Вот интересно посмотреть на природу возникновения такого.. Если это правда конечно

Comment: @KAGG Design в данном случае (применение css и тп) разработчики ВП и темы - не пример и не показатель :). В админке после обновления на 47 в автоплее аж 3 видео. Что вешает файрфокс и грузит ЦП до 100%. Ну и ещё много косяков в построении фейсов. Так что юзабилисты там ещё те.. :) вот топик на оф форуме https://ru.wordpress.org/support/topic/%d0%b2%d0%bf-4-7-%d0%b8-%d1%86%d0%bf-100x4/

Comment: @SeVlad, ахах, ты видимо ничего действительно затратного не видел. CSS ещё как может тормозить. В блоге гугла есть отдельная колонка про то, КАК ПРАВИЛЬНО писать стили, чтобы браузер рендерил слои менее затратно для отрисовки их браузером. Я её прекрасно изучил.

Comment: @SeVlad, я когда свою сайт-галерею делал, в отладке отрисовке заметил, что мой ховер по картинке, который запускает транзишн псевдоэлементов, задействует перерисовку всех остальных элементов, которые находятся ниже по ДОМ. Это затратно и даже очень)

Comment: @SeVlad, вот этот [блог](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/)  гугла

Comment: спасибо, покурим

Answer (score 0):

```css
.b-group-link {
  text-align: center;
}
a {
  font-size: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: -8px 0 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
a > span {
  border-bottom: 7px solid #f00;
  transition: .3s;
}
a > span > span {
  position: relative;
  top: 8px;
}
a:hover > span {
  border-bottom-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="b-group-link">
  <a href="#"><span><span>link text text</span></span></a>
  <br>
  <a href="#"><span><span>link text text<br> link text text</span></span></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Так будет в точности как Вы хотели:

```
.underline{
    color: magenta;
    font-size: 58px;
    font-weight: 900;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -25px 0 0 #0b013e;
}
```

Нашел еще интересный вариант, приглядитесь к нему, он более грамотно реализован, и без box-shadow:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26002260/7489927